# PHP-Gracenote library doesn't return an album_art_url

Tags: php, search, gracenote, albumart

The demo file from the php-gracenote library doesn't return an `album_art_url`. "Moby" is the default search query. Even when I change the search query to something else it still doesn't return an `album_art_url`.

Is the library broken or does Gracenote disable `album_art_url` in searches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of Gracenote's API. It only returns album art when doing a `SINGLE_BEST` lookup (called `BEST_MATCH_ONLY` in the php-gracenote library).

You can pass an extra parameter into any of the search functions of php-gracenote to get album art, but you'll only get the single best result rather than multiple results.

```
// No album art, but multiple results.
$api->searchArtist("Moby");

// You get album art, but only one result.
$api->searchArtist("Moby", Gracenote\WebAPI\GracenoteWebAPI::BEST_MATCH_ONLY);
```